# TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object - XPath

Tags: python, xpath

My Xpath isn't ok.

This line of my code that causes the error:

```
f.write(response.xpath(".//*/div[@class='dataItem'][4]/a/text()").extract())
```

And the error:

```
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write a list to a file. Try doing something like this:

```
data = response.xpath(".//*/div[@class='dataItem'][4]/a/text()").extract()

if data:
    f.write(''.join(data))
```

If you are only interested in the first result of your xpath, the `extract_first` method may better suit your needs.

Instead of a list with the results it returns only the first one, or `None` when none could be extracted. It also supports changing the default return value:

```
>>> response.xpath('//a[0]/text()').extract()
[]
>>> response.xpath('//a[0]/text()').extract_first() is None
True
>>> response.xpath('//a[0]/text()').extract_first(default='not found =(')
'not found =('
```

So, if that's your case you could use something like:

```
data = response.xpath(".//*/div[@class='dataItem'][4]/a/text()").extract_first(default='not_found')
f.write(data)
```